# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare user_defined_function()

Tags: php, oop

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare encrypt() (previously declared in
>   /var/www/html/Medapps_UAT/data/config.inc.php:136)

Included config.inc.php using require_once

**emp_details.php**

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
require('lib/nusoap.php');
require('lib/nusoapmime.php');
require_once("../data/config.inc.php");
require_once("../tax_calculation.php");
.
.
.
?>
```

**tax_calculation.php**

```
<?php
 require_once("data/config.inc.php");
?>
```

as i have used only require_once , but getting function redeclared .

php version 5.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because PHP see's `../data/config.inc.php` and `data/config.inc.php` as different files. It doesn't know it's already included it because the file path is different.

You have a couple of options;

You can use `realpath()` to return the whole path to the file;

```
require_once(realpath('../data/config.inc.php'));
```

Or, you could use the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` property in `$_SERVER`.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'data/config.inc.php');
```

This should ensure these files are loaded only once.

Comment: actually config.inc.php present in project_name/data/config.inc.php . emp_details.php file present in project_name/api/emp_details.php se we use .. to include config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't declare the function in the same name "**encrypt**" in any of the included file such as '**lib/nusoap.php**', '**lib/nusoapmime.php**' or in your current file '**tax_calculation.php**'.

If you are using any **IDE** like **net-beans** or **eclipse**, just import the project in the IDE and search for the function name. You can easily find the total occurrence. Then rename the function name and check.

Comment: encrypt() function is used only file in config.inc.php

Comment: Try hiding the line require_once("../data/config.inc.php"); in emp_details.php and check.

Comment: it works after comment in emp_details.php . but i was unable to access the functions inside config.inc.php using object   **sample code**   `class tax_calculaction {  public function __construct(){ $this->connection=new database() }`  execution stops in constructor